# How to correctly release a C++ console application for different operating systems?

Tags: c++, operating-system, console-application, release, clang++

**POV:** It's 2022. You've developed a console application you called "cowsay" and compiled it with clang++ on a Windows 10 machine. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    if ( argv > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argv; ++i)
            cout << "the cow said: " << argc[i] << endl;
    } else {
        cerr << "Usage: cowsay [word]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly on your machine but now you want to distribute it to Alice (who uses the latest MacOS), and Bob (who uses the latest Ubuntu). How do you go about it?

You've seen that conan (i.e., the C/C++ package manager) exists that seems to allow easy distribution, but it looks like a hassle to have to require people to install conan to run your app. Is there a better solution? What solution do most people use? Is it possible to get users to install your app through the tools they are used to using in those systems (e.g., `choco`, `brew`, `apt-get`, etc.)? Can you get `clang++` to target Alice's and Bob's machines from your machine or do you need to borrow their Ubuntu's and MacOS' computers every time you want to make a release? Are there any good books that address this very annoying (imo) part of development (i.e., perhaps something like the first couple of chapters of *21st Century C* that covers packaging your project and whatnot)?

**P.S.** I've found similar questions asked on the site but none that really addressed an end-to-end distribution strategy for C++ console apps so I've decided to ask my very first stackoverflow question and, well, hope for the best!

Comment: Oh, lovely Alice and Bob ...  Is this an exercise in cryptography?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, nope ~ it's actually a genuine question. Wanna take a stab at it? ;D

Comment: Sorry, it's too many questions in one for me at this time, but the players, Alice and Bob, sounded very familiar :)

Comment: @DanChiarlone How did `clang++` itself end up being available on multiple operating systems?  How is that distributed/installed, etc?  Ironic that the program you're using (clang++) is also a console app, available on multiple operating systems.

Comment: That's a great question~ I'm only running clang++ on Windows but, of course, I'm aware it is distributed everywhere. Regardless, I'm not familiar with how they've manage to distribute across several targets. Are you asking to try to lead me to a solution? Haha

Comment: I've been evesdropping, and I suggest you Google 'cross-compilaion'.

Comment: Hey, @MartinJames~ I've taken a look at clang cross-compilation (as per: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html), but I'm still struggling. I've tried: `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ cowsay.cpp -o bin/cowsay -target x86_64-unknown-linux-unknown`, but, I get: `fatal error: 'iostream' file not found`. **Edit**: FYI, I've managed to compile for Linux just fine on Windows' WSL but I wish I didn't have to because that doesn't solve my problem in compiling for MacOS from Windows too...

Comment: No, this is a yet unsolved problem. Windows and macOS are somewhat easier because you can support (almost) all installations with a single binary. But Linux is hellish. I am distributing a number of binaries through `npm` and I build the Linux binaries for an older glibc version so that they can run on most recent distros. There is also the new `snap` system on Linux which is quite good and it is adopted by most distros. But don't expect to be able to ship a binary software without having separate Linux, macOS and Windows build chains.

Comment: Hmmm, @mmomtchev ~ I didn't really consider using `npm` for distribution; but, tbh, I was really just trying to avoid adding dependencies like such. In any case, I've sorta figured out a way that was good enough for me! I'll update this post soon w/ an answer ;D

Comment: I use `npm` because I am distributing a binary module for Node.js, `conan` would be a better choice for a purely C++ application

Answer (score 0):

The truth of compiling C++ apps for different machines is: **it works best if you have that machine and just compile in it.**

In any case, that doesn't mean you need to *physically* have that computer. For example, to set up my imaginary cowsay project, I've used travis-ci (i.e., a service used to build and test software projects hosted on GitHub and Bitbucket) and easily booted up three VMs to create Windows, Linux, and OSX releases — for free! With that, I managed to make my releases on GitHub (still w/ travis-ci) and all was good.

Next, for a user-friendly installation, I decided to write my own shell and PowerShell scripts that can be run with `curl`/`iex` directly from the web (largely inspired by [Homebrew's](https://brew.sh/) setup).

In any case, here are a couple of resources that helped me:

1. Setting up travis-ci for multiple OSes: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/
2. Making GitHub releases with travis-ci: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/
3. Homebrew's heavily commented shell script for installation: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh

P.S. travis-ci has a limit of how much you can do w/ it for free. If you want an alternative for it, I suggest looking at GitHub Actions.